# Вложенные циклы на Java

Tags: java

Из цикла, выводящего 1-15, нужно сделать цикл 1-5, 12-20, 33-45 (1*5, 2*6, 3*11).

Что я делаю не так? Вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (a <= 15) {

        i = 0;
        int k = 1;
        while (i < 5) {
            if (i%4>0) k++;
            a = a*k;
            System.out.print(a + " ");
            a++;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: можете продолжить последовательность? не совсем понятно как формируются следующие числа

Comment: номер строки умножить на элемент. 1*1 1*2 1*3 1*4 1*5 2*6 2*7 2*8 2*9 2*10 3*11 3*12 3*13 3*14 3*15

Answer (score 1):

```
Все просто, сравнивайте код и все поймете

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int k = a; k < a+5; k++) System.out.print(k * i + " ");
        a+=5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вывод: 1 2 3 4 5 12 14 16 18 20 33 36 39 42 45 64 68 72 76 80 105 110 115 120 125 . Требуется : 1 2 3 4 5 12 14 16 18 20 33 36 39 42 45

Comment: Ну что вы, в самом деле... Измените в первом цикле с i<6 на i<4 и  будет вывод 2 3 4 5 12 14 16 18 20 33 36 39 42 45. Условия задачи так сформулированы, что приходится догадываться, где границы вывода. Последовательность то правильная. Код подправил

Answer (score 0):

ну пока лучше ничего не придумал:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    while (a <= 15) {
        if(a<6){
           System.out.print(a*1 + " ");
        }else if(a < 11){
           System.out.print(a*2 + " ");
        }else {
           System.out.print(a*3 + " ");
        }
        a++;
    }
```

---

вариант с for выглядит получше и покороче:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i <= 15; i++) {
        if(i < 6){
           System.out.print(i*1 + " ");
        }else if(i < 11){
           System.out.print(i*2 + " ");
        }else {
           System.out.print(i*3 + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
    final int step = 5;
    final int limit = 15;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
        //определяем множитель
        int factor = i / step;
        //обрабатываем случай для чисел на границе отрезков
        factor += i % step == 0 ? 0 : 1;

        //вывод
        System.out.print((factor * i) + " ");
        if (i % step == 0) System.out.println();
    }
```

и такая последовательность:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>   12 14 16 18 20
>   33 36 39 42 45

Comment: спасибо. интересное решение. только не понял, почему условие для шага (step от 0 до 1, а не от 0 до 3?)

Comment: Не понимаю про что вы